# Some messages sent to tokio::mpsc::unbounded_channel isn't received

Tags: multithreading, rust, websocket, rust-tokio

I have a tokio_tungstenite (websocket) server with three threads that share list of connected clients with UnboundedSender to send messages to client.

In one thread, I broadcast some data to all clients every 2 seconds (using their unbounded_channel).

Other two threads are created for each client, one handle messages from clients, other handle messages from unbounded_channel to send them to client.

The problem is, thread that receives messages from unbounded_channel doesn't always receive data that I broadcast from first thread, especially when there are more than 1 client.

Here is my code:

```rust
use futures_util::{future, StreamExt, TryStreamExt, SinkExt};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json::Value;
use std::{
    collections::HashMap,
    net::SocketAddr,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
    time::Instant,
};
use tokio::{net::TcpListener, sync::mpsc::{UnboundedSender, self}};
use tungstenite::Message;

mod packets;
use packets::*;

static REFRESH_TIME: u64 = 2000;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Client {
    pub send: UnboundedSender<Message>
}

#[derive(Debug, Default, Clone)]
pub struct State {
    pub clients: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<uuid::Uuid, Client>>>
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let g_state = State::default();

    let state_clone = g_state.clone();
    tokio::task::spawn(async move {
        let mut state = state_clone;
        loop {
            send_clients(&mut state).await;
            std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(REFRESH_TIME));
        }
    });

    let stream = TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:25342").await.unwrap();
    loop {
        let (socket, addr) = stream.accept().await.unwrap();
        let state_clone = g_state.clone();
        tokio::task::spawn(async move {
            let self_uuid = uuid::Uuid::new_v4();
            let state = state_clone;
            let (tx, mut rx) = mpsc::unbounded_channel::<Message>();

            {
                let mut clients = state.clients.lock().unwrap();
                clients.insert(
                    self_uuid,
                    Client {
                        send: tx
                    },
                );
            }

            let websocket = tokio_tungstenite::accept_async(socket).await.unwrap();
            let (mut outgoing, mut incoming) = websocket.split();

            let incoming = incoming.try_for_each(|msg| {
                handle_message(msg, &state, &mut clients, self_uuid);

                future::ok(())
            });
            
            tokio::task::spawn(async move {
                loop {
                    let message = rx.recv().await.unwrap();
                    outgoing.send(message).await.unwrap();
                }
            });

            incoming.await.unwrap();

            {
                let mut clients = state.clients.lock().unwrap();
                println!("{} @ {}", "[x] Client disconnected!".red(), self_uuid);
                clients.remove(&self_uuid).unwrap();
            }
        });
    }
}

async fn send_clients(state: &mut State) {
    let mut clients = state.clients.lock().unwrap();
    for client in clients.iter() {
        let packet = serde_json::to_string(&get_clients_packet_from_clients(&clients)).unwrap();
        client.1.send.send(Message::Text(packet)).unwrap();
    }
}
```

Note that, in actual code, `send_clients` actually finds first client that meets the requirements and sends other packet to it. And it always works, but only first time.

Comment: Did you figure this out?